# How to move the scale?

Tags: html, css

I have created the scale shown in the image below using pure HTML and CSS. The markings at the bottom of the scale are coming from an array that I'm looping over. Now, I need a functionality that initially the pillars will be empty but when I click on let's say 3, pillars 1,2,3 should be filled with yellow color and circle should move to 3 similar to what's happening on this [site](https://good.co/career-quiz/?cid=homepage_corpsite_CTA_get_started) if you scroll down a bit and take the quiz. Can anyone please help me achieve this or guide me in the right direction?

[image]

```
<div class="rating-type__bar">
          <div class="rating-type__circle"></div>

          <div class="rating-type__bar-wrapper rating-type__bar-left" *ngFor="let opt of _element.options">
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 100%; opacity: 1;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 80%; opacity: 0.8;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">4</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 60%; opacity: 0.6;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 40%; opacity: 0.4;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 20%; opacity: 0.2;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">1</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rating-type__bar-wrapper rating-type__bar-center">
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 10%; opacity: 0.1;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">0</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rating-type__bar-wrapper rating-type__bar-right">
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 20%; opacity: 0.2;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 40%; opacity: 0.4;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 60%; opacity: 0.6;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 80%; opacity: 0.8;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">4</div>
              </div>
              <div class="rating-type__pipe rating-type__pipe--active">
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-pillar">
                      <span style="height: 100%; opacity: 1;" class="rating-type__pipe-pillar-bg"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rating-type__pipe-text">5</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have to provide your code so someone can tell how you implemented that scale. The image isn't enough.

Comment: CSS Would also be helpful to make reproducing much more easier

Comment: If you want to implement somethinkg like that chart, i think you're on the wrong way.
It just a background, with a resizable overlay.
More details:
There are 2 layers, grey bars on the bottom, and colored on top.
The mouse event will change the size of the top one.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't answer the question but I spent like an hour on this so I might as well share my progress:

```js
"use strict";

const bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar"),
  barCovers = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-cover");
for (let i = 5; i > -6; i--) {
  const bar = bars[Math.abs(i - 5)];
  bar.style.left = Math.abs(i - 5) * 20 + 40 + "px";
  bar.style.height = (Math.abs(i) + 1) * 7 + "px";
  
  const barCover = barCovers[Math.abs(i - 5)];
  barCover.style.left = Math.abs(i - 5) * 20 + 40 + "px";
  barCover.style.height = (Math.abs(i) + 1) * 7 + "px";
  barCover.style.backgroundColor = "#d5e312";
  //barCover.style.width = "0px";
  //barCover.style.display = "none";
}

const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.style.position = "absolute";
slider.style.left = "37px";
slider.style.width = "218px";
slider.style.bottom = "150px";

setInterval(() => {
  const middleBar = barCovers[5];
  if (slider.value < 50) {
    const width =
      (Math.abs(slider.value - 50) < 5
        ? Math.abs(slider.value - 50)
        : 4) * 2;
    middleBar.style.width = width + "px";
    middleBar.style.left = 148 - width + "px";
      
  } else if (slider.value > 50) {
    middleBar.style.left = "148px";
    middleBar.style.width =
      (slider.value - 50 < 5
        ? slider.value - 50
        : 4) * 2 + "px";
  } else {
    middleBar.style.width = "0px";
  }
  
  /*for (let i = 5; i > -6; i--) {
    if (i !== 0) {
      const barCover = barCovers[Math.abs(i - 5)];
      if (slider.value - 50 < -i * 7 && i > 0) {
        const width =
          (Math.abs(slider.value - 50) - i * 6.8 < 17
            ? Math.abs(slider.value - 50) - i * 6.8
            : 16);
        barCover.style.width = width + "px";
        barCover.style.left = 155 - i * 19.5 - width + "px";
      } else {
        barCover.style.width = "0px";
      }
    }
  }*/
  for (let i = 5; i > -6; i--) {
    if (i !== 0) {
      const barCover = barCovers[Math.abs(i - 5)];
      if (slider.value - 50 < -i * 7) {
        barCover.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        barCover.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}, 50);
```

```css
body, html {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.temp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.bar, .bar-cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#slider {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<div class="bar-cover"></div>
<input type="range" id="slider"/>
```